# Basic String Manipulation,removal of last character in While loop

Tags: java, collections

I am struggling with this basic code below ,

how do i prevent the last comma "," from being appended to the String.

```
    String outScopeActiveRegionCode="";

    List<String> activePersons=new ArrayList<String>();

    HashSet<String> outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet=new HashSet<String>();

    for (String person : activePersons) {

       outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet.add(person); 

    }
       Iterator itr = outScopeActiveRegionCodeSet.iterator();

             while(itr.hasNext()){
                outScopeActiveRegionCode+=itr.next();
                outScopeActiveRegionCode+=",";
             }
```

Comment: May be you can do another hasNext() before appending comma

Comment: Consider using a StringBuilder instead of appending to a String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Id actually do it the other way around, id append the comma before on all cases except the first, its easier.

```
boolean isFirst = true;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    if(isFirst) {
        isFirst = false;
    } else {
        outScopeActiveRegionCode+=",";
    }
    outScopeActiveRegionCode+=itr.next();
}
```

The reason for this is that it is much simpler to detect the first case than the last case.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
String delimiter = "";

while(itr.hasNext()){
    outScopeActiveRegionCode += delimiter;
    outScopeActiveRegionCode += itr.next();
    delimiter = ",";
}
```

Comment: I like this too, I have to admit I have no idea how efficient things are in the background, but would assigning a value to delimiter variable each time round be more expensive than checking a boolean variable each time round to see if you are on the first element or not?  Just a thought.

Comment: I just made some tests, and it seems that assignment is faster. Of course you will only will notice it as the List size grows. For most of the cases, it won't matter, so both solutions are good.